# Nested jquery selectors triggering both parent and child specific events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table with the following structure

> - table#Main
> - - tbody
> - - - tr.Row
> - - - - td
> - - - - - input.EditRow

My jquery looks like this:

```
        $("table#Main > tbody > tr.Row").live("click", function (e) {
            RowClick($(this));
        });

        $(".EditRow").live("click", function (e) {
            EditRow($(this));
        });
```

My problem is that if I click the .EditRow button and call the EditRow function, the RowClick function is called immediately after.

After doing some research on the site, I saw that others got around this problem by using either one of the other of the following commands.

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

I tried them on both functions, in different combinations but couldn't figure it out. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you! <3

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It seems that there were some changes in this regard. Using `e.stopPropagation()` works for me if I have `1.4.3` or later loaded. [Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dwJU/) Click the link, and you only get one alert. Switch the library on the left to use 1.4.2, and you get both alerts.

Comment: jquery-1.4.1.js this is the one that came with my version of Visual Studio 2010. I'll download the latest version now...

Comment: @patrick dw: It really works for you? Then the documentation should be updated.

Comment: @Felix: I updated my comment with an example. I was pretty surprised too. Was about to leave an answer, but thought I had better test it first.

Comment: @patrick dw: Yep I see it. Nice to know :)

Comment: @patrick dw: You can still post it as answer. I know it is already given, but without any information about why. You will even get an upvote from me ;)

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, but that's alright. I'm past the cap anyway. But the more I think about this, it makes me shudder a little. I mean it would seem that jQuery would need to test every selector that was passed to `.live()` to see if the one that called `e.stopPropagation` was a child of it. Seems terribly inefficient. EDIT: Or maybe it's not quite that bad. I suppose it just needs to stop propagation on those elements in the chain from `e.target` to `document` that matched a `.live()` selector. Who knows.

Comment: @patrick dw: I'm not sure about the performance of DOM methods, but if it would use `Node.prototype.contains` then it might be ok. But that is all speculation, I honestly don't know (and it would be still bad if you have a lot of `live` event listeners). EDIT: Whatever :)

Comment: @Felix: I didn't know about `contains()`. Nice! I agree that it's bad to have too many `.live()` listeners. Of course, in my book, one `.live()` is too many. ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw: Hehe... `contains` is (or was) not supported by Firefox though (and I just saw again that it is not part of a standard but supported by all other browsers). Check this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2006/01/contains_for_mo.html Oh and jQuery has it's own `contains()` method too.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, I looked it up just after you mentioned it. To bad that they're not even supporting it in v4. Regarding jQuery, somehow I get more excited about DOM methods. Probably because I'm still finding them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** As @patrick demonstrates in his comment, `event.stopPropagation()` should work from **jQuery 1.4.3** on.

---

**For jQuery 1.4.2 and below:**

The problem is that both event handlers are bound to the root of the DOM tree, due to [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> The handler passed to `.live()` is never bound to an element; instead, `.live()` binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree.

So [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) has not effect anymore (both event handlers are that the same level):

> Since the `.live()` method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events.

Use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) instead and reverse the the order of binding the event handlers (otherwise it won't work as event handlers are called in the order they bound):

```
$(".EditRow").live("click", function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    EditRow($(this));
});

$("table#Main > tbody > tr.Row").live("click", function (e) {
    RowClick($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Felix Kling! This worked perfectly after I updated to the latest version of JQuery!

Comment: @Robodude: Yeah but I hope you are using `e.stopPropgation()` now, as this seems to work fine. Anyway, I will leave this as answer for the other versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".EditRow").live("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    EditRow($(this));
});
```

**Should work just fine.**