# How to implement event order in parent/child elements using jquery

Tags: event-handling, event-bubbling, jquery

I have a parent & child elements in my web page where both have separate event handlers defined for them. I have tested in firefox, where the event handler for parent element gets executed first. I want it to execute the other way - child element's event handler getting executed first.

I have read about making use of bind, stopPropagation, preventDefault etc. make that happen but I am a bit confused as a to how to get this working? Can somebody shed some light on this topic?

Here is how I am implementing the event handling....

```
$('#Sidebar ul li .DeleteList').live('click', function(e) {
        alert("I was deleted");
});

$('#Sidebar ul').delegate('li', 'click', function(e) {
        alert("I was selected");
});
```

[image]

Comment: you can refer below link for this task.. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684602/nested-jquery-selectors-triggering-both-parent-and-child-specific-events) Thanks.

Comment: I already did that. It doesn't work in my case. Changing the "delegate" being used for parent element to "live" does the trick bu why is still beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not be consistent and just use `.live()` for both? :D

```
$('#Sidebar ul li .DeleteList').live('click', function(e) {
    alert("I was deleted");
});

$('#Sidebar ul li').live('click', function(e) {
    alert("I was selected");
});
```

This way 'deleted' gets triggered first.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9sBD/